# Creating a put api request using Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, mern

I am using MERN stack and Redux. I am finding it difficult to create an api and action for updating the MongoDb. I have two models, i want to find one model by id and then update it with an object of the other model passed in. This is what i have for my api and actions. Can anyone give me some advice on how to finish this off and how i pass the comment to be added to the api? When i test this on Postman it says it has worked but no object is returned when i use an id in the url. I also changed res.json(subject) to res.send("Put req success") but this text wasn't shown either. PLEASE HELP! :(

api

```
subjectRouter.put("/subject/:_id", (req, res) => {
  Subject.findById(req.params._id, (err, subject) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
    // what goes here to update the subject?
    // the propery to be updated is 'comments'
    // which is an array of comment objects
    console.log(subject.json);
    Subject.updateOne()
    res.json(subject);
  });
});
```

action

```
export const updateSubject = () => (dispatch) => {
  console.log("updateSubject called");
  fetch("/api/subjects/Subject/:_id")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((subject) =>
      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_SUBJECT,
        subjects: subject,
      })
    );
};
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you call updateSubject()?

Comment: it's seem the api take `_id` but you didn't pass it in `fetch` call .

Comment: I think the "redux way " of handling API calls is using `thunks`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's seem the api take `_id` as param but you didn't pass it in fetch call, here try this :

```
export const updateSubject = (id) => (dispatch) => {
  console.log("updateSubject called");
  fetch(`/api/subjects/Subject/${id}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((subject) =>
      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_SUBJECT,
        subjects: subject,
      })
    );
};
```

Comment: Thank you, do you know how i would update the subject that is returned? So what i need to add to Subject.updateOne()

Comment: where you want to update on backend ?? use mongoose findByIdAndUpdate() .